# What is a Pattern that is part of the Design System?

Tags: design-system, design-theory, definition

I am researching Patterns and I am confused by the following definition.

> Patterns are reusable combinations of components that solve common
> user problems. These best practice solutions help users achieve their
> goals and help ensure consistency across experiences.

*Source: https://atlassian.design/patterns*

What is meant by a component that solves common user problems, we are already creating components, why don't we do this under component and create a new sub-branch called Pattern.

My question is actually what is Pattern and why is it separated from the component category?

Comment: Can you supply with the source of this definitionm please ?

Comment: https://atlassian.design/patterns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the confusion comes from the definition you've encountered. The definition you've mentioned doesn't align well with commonly accepted understandings of UX patterns.

UX Patterns are more aligned with user journeys and/or user flows, comprising a series of steps that users frequently undertake in a repeated and consistent manner. As such, **they are processes rather than mere design elements.** These processes may or may not include specific design elements, making it clear that patterns aren't exclusive to UI design or even design in general.

To illustrate, consider the login process: most users are familiar with how to log in to a site, and most login processes are similar across platforms. That's why libraries of common UX patterns reflect this similarity across various sites. Sometimes some of these UX patterns are included in guidelines.

**Because of the nature of UX patterns, you can categorize them into other patterns like [dark patterns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_pattern) and [anti-patterns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-pattern).**

**A dark pattern is deliberately designed to mislead or deceive users** *(which is why I say the definition you've encountered doesn't make sense)*. An anti-pattern, meanwhile, **is a pattern designed with good intentions that ultimately fails** due to factors like poor design, inadequate testing, technological changes, or accessibility issues.

Moreover, **UX patterns can include elements that are entirely unrelated to design**, such as [haptic interactions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haptic_technology) on mobile apps or AR.

Thus, while UX patterns may have some overlap with design elements, they can also be entirely distinct. This separation is why they generally aren't included together in a design system (and in my experience, UX patterns are rarely part of a design system).

UI design patterns, on the other hand, **do require the presence of design elements, unlike UX Patterns**.

From [UI patterns](https://ui-patterns.com/patterns/):

> User Interface Design patterns are recurring solutions that solve
> common design problems. Design patterns are standard reference points
> for the experienced user interface designer.
>
> Design patterns provide a common language between designers. They
> allow for debate over alternatives, where merely mentioning the name
> of a design pattern implicitly carries much more meaning than merely
> the name.

Beyond the need for design elements, UI patterns also relate to [affordances](https://dorve.com/blog/affordances-are-you-aware-of-its-importance/) and familiarity. We humans tend to look for patterns in everything, and UI design is no exception. Once we encounter a particular pattern, **we anticipate certain behaviors from the design elements and often expect related elements to appear**.

For instance, after filling a form, I expect clicking a submit button to lead to some form of confirmation (a thank you page, message, popup, etc.). If clicking the submit button instead opens a video, the pattern is broken, making it unrecognizable as a pattern at all.

In short, now that I've explained the peculiarities: you could call a pattern a collection of entities that include both design elements as well as user behaviors and affordances. Whether you include them on a design system will highly depend on the product to design. If it's a website I wouldn't include it, but that's subjective.

Answer (score 2):

Patterns are just as much about UX as UI, and though they are made up of combinations of components, they aren't components themselves. Some examples of patterns include:

1. Filters
2. Login screen
3. Empty states
4. Multi-step forms
5. Search

These are made up of components that behave in a specific way and solve a specific user problem. They relate to the UI, but also the UX and expected behavior. For example, filters on a single site might look different depending on what they are filtering. However, the way they are expected to behave is usually the same. UX patterns help designers maintain consistency of experience when they combine components.